# Why doesn't this work? Filtering data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to match up 3 inputs to a set of data. Only if all three meet the criteria will it add all those three criteria to results. Those will be displayed later. I shortened the data set to one object for simplicity right now. Thank you!

```
var departureDate = $("#departure-date").val();
var returnDate = $("#return-date").val();
var city = $("#city").val();

var places = [{
  place: "New York City",
  avalibleArival: ["3 December, 2015", "4 December, 2015"],
  avalibleReturn: ["4 December, 2015", "6 December, 2015"]
}];

var results = [];
places.forEach(function (x) {
  if (x.place === city) {
    console.log("found city");
    places.forEach(function (y) {
      if (y.avalibleArival === departureDate) {
        console.log("Found correct Departure Date");
        places.forEach(function (z) {
          if (z.avalibleReturn === returnDate) {
            console.log("yay you found a Full match");
            results.push([x, y, z]);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't there missing `]` for `places` array?

Comment: sorry my bad that didn't get coppied over correctly. There IS a ] in my code to end the places var

Comment: In addition to @IvanSivak, a `;` for end instruction too. Finally it will show as `var places = [{ ...... }];`

Comment: So, what does it do currently, and what did you expect it to do instead? (this should be part of  your question.)

Comment: From what I can see, your inner loops are looping over `places` again, when it should be looping over one of the sub arrays instead. and, the 3rd loop shouldn't be inside the second. Lastly, .some would likely be better than forEach in this case so that you can exit after you find a valid match. but... you don't even need the inner loops anyway.

Comment: I get the "found city" in console but I do not think I am doing this correctly for the multiple values for avalibleArival and avalibleReturn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 major things are wrong with your code, one stops it working the other is just *not necessary*

1. In the code `if (z.avalibleReturn === returnDate) {` and similar for `avalibleArival` you are comparing a string to an array, that will never equate true
2. You are looping over the `places` array inside each loop of the `places` array - this is not only unnecessary, but highly inefficient. You don't need to do it.

I think what you're after is along the lines of

```
places.forEach(function (x) {
  if (x.place === city) {
    console.log("found city");
    if(x.avalibleArival.indexOf(departureDate) > -1){
        console.log("Found correct Departure Date");
        if(x.avalibleReturn .indexOf(returnDate) > -1){
            console.log("yay you found a Full match");
            results.push([x, y, z]);
        }    
    }    
  }
});
```